# Sencha Touch 2.x form panel width/layout

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've got the beginnings of an app that has a basic login form, however when using the `formpanel` xtype, the width of the component becomes basically double the width of it's parent container.

For example:

[image: Form panel width]

If I simply change `xtype: 'formpanel'` to `xtype: 'panel'` it fits perfectly:

[image: Panel width]

My question is:
Would I be losing any major inbuilt functionality if I simply use `xtype: 'panel'` over `'formpanel'`? Considering that I was already planning to override any Sencha validation with my custom stuff.

And I guess bonus points to anyone that has a solution to the width problem that doesn't require me using `xtype: 'panel'`.

Code is below:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.LoginDetails',{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    requires: [
        'Ext.Button',
        'Ext.TitleBar',
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.field.Text',
        'Ext.field.Email',
        'Ext.field.Select',
        'Ext.field.Toggle',
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],
    config:{
        layout: 'card',
        showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
        cls: 'view-login-details',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            html: 'Titlebar',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                ui: 'back',
                html: 'Back',
                cls: 'btn-login-details-back',
                id: 'login-details-back'
            }]
        },{
            xtype: 'panel', // OR formpanel
            flex: 1,
            cls: 'login-details-form',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'first_name',
                placeHolder: 'First Name',
                required: true
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'last_name',
                placeHolder: 'Last Name',
                required: true
            },{
                xtype: 'emailfield',
                name: 'email',
                placeHolder: 'Email',
                required: true
            },{
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                placeHolder: 'City',
                required: true,
                options: [
                    {text: 'Auckland', value: 'Auckland'},
                    {text: 'Wellington', value: 'Wellington'},
                    {text: 'Christchurch', value: 'Christchurch'},
                    {text: 'Other', value: 'Other'}
                ],
                listeners: {
                    change: function(item,newValue,oldValue,event){
                        if(newValue === 'Other'){
                            Ext.Msg.alert('City Selection', 'There are only items in Auckland, Wellington and Christchurch');
                        }
                    }
                }
            },{
                xtype: 'togglefield',
                name: 'terms_conditions',
                label: 'I have read and agree to the Terms & Conditions and Privacy Policy',
                labelAlign: 'right'
            },{
                xtype: 'togglefield',
                name: 'opt_in',
                label: 'I would like to opt-in to ongoing communication from X and Y',
                labelAlign: 'right'
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Get Started',
                cls: 'btn-banner',
                id: 'login-details-get-started'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Were you actually needing a `card` layout for this? If this is your only view, try changing your `LoginDetails` to extend an `Ext.form.Panel` and setting the items as normal.

Comment: @jprofitt actually, ignore my other comment. I've tried with `fit` as well as `card`... no glory there.

Comment: The viewport itself is a card layout. Are you sure you need this one to be as well? If it's possible for you to refactor this to be just the `formpanel`, and push items onto the viewport instead, it may help you out with this view and a general architecture of the views. At any rate, since you're docking your toolbar at the top anyway, you shouldn't need to put your form into an additional `panel` -- unless I'm misunderstanding how your other views are being displayed.

Comment: A good rule of thumb to remember with a `fit` layout is that it's going to take the first non-docked item and make it the size of the view.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the insights. Yeah this view is the only one with *that* particular toolbar, so that's why it's contained within that panel.

Comment: Have you tried making it a `formpanel` and removing the `flex`?

Comment: Yeah. Removing the flex makes it not show up at all. It collapses to 0 height.

Comment: That's likely because of the `card` layout. Can you try it with just a `vbox` layout and see if that works?

Comment: Yeah it's no longer collapsing, but still has the width issue originally described. It's fine though --- am I losing major functionality by using just a regular panel w/ custom validation?

Comment: Hmm, possibly some CSS that is getting applied to a form panel that isn't to a panel? Or to a form field that is when it's in a form panel but not a panel?

Comment: Changing this to a regular `panel` will cause you to lose some of the benefits of the `formpanel`. Things like `getValues()` is quite useful.